# Click event triggeres twice but are only set once

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6

I have a weird problem where a click event is triggered twice, which I have no idea why is happening.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jnht2re/) click one of the names so that the toggle button will trigger, it won't happen if you click outside the label element, then it will actually only trigger once.

I am attaching an event to all elements with the class of 'testit', when I log the elements I get a nodelist with a length of 1, when I log how many times the foreach loop is running it is running once.

[image]

If I delete the Javascript no events are attached.

```
    // SELECTER DEN FEATURED JOKE
    $sql = " SELECT t1.cat_id,
            t1.cat_name,
            t1.cat_parent,
            t1.cat_type
            FROM categories t1
            ORDER BY t1.cat_parent,
            t1.cat_name";
    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($count > 0) {
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $orders = [];
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $cat_parent = $row['cat_parent'];
            if($cat_parent == 0){
                $orders[$row['cat_id']]['parent'] = [
                    'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
                    'cat_name' => $row['cat_name'],
                    'cat_parent' => $row['cat_parent'],
                    'cat_type' => $row['cat_type']
                ];
                continue;
            }

            if ($cat_parent != 0) {
                $orders[$cat_parent][] = [
                    'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
                    'cat_name' => $row['cat_name'],
                    'cat_parent' => $row['cat_parent'],
                    'cat_type' => $row['cat_type']
                ];
                continue;
            }
        }

        $filter_html  = '<form id="filter__form" class="filter__form testit">';
        $filter_html .= '<ul class="filter__ul main">';
        foreach($orders as $order){
            $cat_id     = escape($order['parent']['cat_id']);
            $para       = escape($order['parent']['cat_id']);
            $cat_name   = escape($order['parent']['cat_name']);
            $cat_parent = escape($order['parent']['cat_parent']);
            $cat_type   = escape($order['parent']['cat_type']);

            $filter_html .= '<label class="filter__label parent" for="filter_'.$cat_id.'">';
            $filter_html .= '<p class="noselect">'.$cat_name.'</p>';
            $filter_html .= '<input id="filter_'.$cat_id.'" type="checkbox" value="'.$cat_id.'" name="cat['.$cat_id.']" class="cat_parent" data-show="cat_subs_'.$cat_id.'">';
            $filter_html .= '<i></i>';
            $filter_html .= '</label>';
        }
        $filter_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="'.$_SESSION['CSRFToken'].'">';
        $filter_html .= '</ul>';
        $filter_html .= '</form>';
    }
?>

<div class="filter__head">
    <h3 class="">
        Filter - Dashboard
    </h3>
</div>

<?php
    echo $filter_html;
?>
```

The Javascript

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {


        var testit = document.querySelectorAll('.testit');

        console.log(testit);

        testit.forEach(function(e){
            console.log('TESTIT');
            e.addEventListener('click', function(){
                alert('Hello world');
            });
        });
   });
```

So the event runs twice that is confirmed in the console or by making an alert when the event is fired, the length of the node object is 1 which is also confirmed if I console it, if I delete the Javascript no events are attached, so what is going on?

If I make a button at the bottom of the `echo $filter_html` with a class of testit, and I click that one it will only trigger once, what's the difference how can it trigger twice in one particular element and once in another, the same event?.

If I attach a mouseup event everything only triggers once.

If I comment out the label element it will not trigger twice? why is this happening?

CSS

```
.filter__head h3{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: start;
    color: #4a4a4a;
}
.filter__form{
    max-height: 70vh;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
    padding: 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label > input {
  display: none;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label i {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: .25s .09s;
  position: relative;
  background: #d8d9db;
  box-sizing: initial;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label i:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  transition: .25s;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label > input:checked + i {
  background: #4bd865;
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label > input:checked + i:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
          transform: translateX(20px);
}
.filter__form .filter__ul .filter__label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: "So the code runs twice that is confirmed in the console" Which code? What in the console shows up twice? This question is super unclear.

Comment: I console.log how many times the code is running the add event, which is once, it is also showed in the fiddle take a look :)

Comment: But you said something is running twice, what is that something? From the code you've posted, things seem to run once, so what event is running twice?

Comment: Sorry that where unclear, the click event is running twice when I console the event itself

Comment: When I click "testit" I only get one alert, you're saying you get 2? Really it would make a huge difference if you could trim down your example. For instance, it doesn't seem like CSS is necessary to demonstrate a small JS question.

Comment: Try clicking one of the elements with a name, I get 2 alerts here in Firefox, edit: and also in chrome

Comment: It's beacuse of the `label` elements wrapping the other elements. `label` triggers an onclick on the input it contains every time you click inside of the label element.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant put that as an answer with an explanation and i will mark it as correct and upvote :)

Comment: I would, but I don't know how to fix the problem. The fix depends on what you're reallly doing in the click handler. Preventing the default action is not a good solution, since it prevents the input state to change when clicking on the label. So, if you first post the real event handler, then I'll take a look at it and propose a fix in an answer.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant what I went with was a mouseup event instead, that works perfectly fine for my particular case

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 If you're interested in event delegation, [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gdex5af/1/) showing how you can organize all the click events on the document with a simple code. The system can be integrated to OOP based code and it also can handle dynamically added elements without any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second click event on the form is triggered by clicking on the `label` element wrapping the input and the other elements. A label element triggers a click event on the associated input element. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> "*When a `label` is clicked or tapped and it is associated with a form control, the resulting click event is also raised for the associated control.*"

Preventing the default action of clicking the label is not a solution, since it would prevent the state change of the associated checkbox. A fix would be to attach `input` event instead of `click` to execute what you need when the state of the checkbox is changed.

If there are more inputs to listen in the form, things are getting a bit more complex, as usual when using this type of the event delegation. In that case you've to check the event really was triggered from an element you expect to response the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you are attaching the event to the form itself, that's the only element with a class `testit`.

Try adding the event listener to the inputs instead, and use the **[event object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp)** to identify each input:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.cat_parent'); 
  inputs.forEach(function(input) { 
     input.addEventListener('click', function(event) { // you need to pass the event
       alert(event.currentTarget.id); // Now in the event object you have just the one that was clicked
      });
});
```

Comment: The technique OP uses is called _event delegation_, and it works perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: Yes, you can use event delegation too